# Python Run Code in VS Code results in system cannot find the path specified

Tags: python

When I right-click a .py file and select Run Code I get "The system cannot find the path specified."  If I right-click and select Run Python File in Terminal it works great!  Any clues?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you didn't set up the visual studio code environment correctly.

I would advise looking through the documentation starting here:

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/setup-overview

Comment: I followed those steps.  For some reason, Run Code is running [Running] /usr/bin/env python3 and my python install Python 3.7.2 interpreter is simply python

Answer (score 0):

I assume the Run Code you mentioned is run without debugging, if your folder or file name contains & symbol it'll confuse terminal to look up the file/folder. I realised it showed && while looking the folder/file....that's what I solved my case